# Where did the Composite Collider go?

Tags: unity, collider

Some of my GameObjects have 2 Sprites nested under them, like how Cat and Snake are nested under Sprites:

[image]

The "Cat + Snake" parent GameObject has a Composite Collider 2D and a RigidBody 2D on it (the only other Component is a State Machine with my graphs in it).

[image]

Here's the settings for the Cat grandchild (the Snake is identical).

[image]

It used to be that if I went into Scene view and clicked on the Cat + Snake in the Hierarchy... I would see the Composite Collider over the Cat and Snake (it looked like a rectangle).  Then I could play with the Offset Distance setting, and the rectangle would become a RoundRect.

But I must've tweaked something somehow, and I can no longer see the Composite Collider!  But the colliders to seem to be working, as I'm able to click on the Cat, the Snake and the Words.

I'm thinking I must've done something to make the Colliders not appear in Game View, or somehow downgraded them in some respect... any idea what it might have been?

Comment: Is the Button `Gizmos` in the editor (not on a component) maybe toggled off?

Comment: The gizmos were not toggled off...  but just in case I tried toggling off and then on again, and then restarting.

Comment: I couldn't figure this out, so I am going to try another approach instead of using Composite Collider here.  Feel free to close this question if appropriate - thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Myself, I was able to fix this by navigating to the child colliders, unticking the "used by composite" box, then ticking it again and navigating back to the parent. After repeating that for each child, their combined composite collider gizmos showed up when selecting the parent.

Comment: Just tried this but no luck, alas!